# returning data to index.js node express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Why is users undefined?

db.js:

```html
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var users;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ExpressApp2', function(err, db) {

    users = db.collection('usercollection');
    users.find().each(function(err, doc) {
        console.log(doc);
    });
});
```

index.js

```html
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


 /* GET Userlist page. */
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
    var users = require('../db').getUsers();
    if (users==undefined)
        res.send('undefined');
    else
        res.send('found something');
});
    




 module.exports = router;
```

The collection is correctly retrieved from Mongo and logged to screen, but users in index.js gives undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ExpressApp2', function(err, db)       {
    users = db.collection('usercollection');
    users.find().each(function(err, doc) {
        console.log(doc);
    });
});
```

should be

```
module.exports.getUsers = function() {
    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ExpressApp2', function(err, db)       {
        return db.collection('usercollection');
    });
}
```

I'm presuming that

```
users.find().each(function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
});
```

is part of your debugging and what you actually want to return is the user collection.  The important bit is adding the block to module.exports as getUsers().

Comment: I agree, this is more what I want, but I had also tried similar and still I get undefined returned to the browser. db.collection contains data. Could it be the way that I call the function from index.js?

Answer (score 0):

In db.js you are not using module.exports to export your users.

Your code in index.js suggests db.js exports an object with a getUsers function but it does not.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this async call in the end.
index.js

```
router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) {
var d = require('../db');
d.getUsers('input', function(users) {
    users.each(function(err, doc) {
        res.send(doc);
        return false;
    });

});
```

});